# error lauchoptions undeclared IOS4?

Tags: iphone

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

```
// Handle launching from a notification
UILocalNotification *localNotif =[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

if (localNotif) {
    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",localNotif);
}

return YES;
```

i am getting **lauchoptions** undeclared  my os veriosn is 4  and xcode i 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Well, where are you getting the variable "launchOptions" from?  Presumably, you're using

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Did you rename the argument?  Perhaps you need to show more of your code...